# Bootstrap Modal Form Validation Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-modal

I am working with form inside Modal. I want to validate it but it's not working.

Details:

Instead of having a Submit Button, i have an anchor link named Login to submit my form using ajax. But before that i want to make some validations.
I am facing error in console

```
lendingPage.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: username.removeClass is not a function
```

Please help me in finding my mistake.

lendingPage.js

```
    $('#login_Modal').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $('#loginUsername').val();
        var password = $('#loginPassword').val();

            // Check if there is an entered value
    if(username.length>0) {
              // Remove the errors highlight
      username.removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');

    } else {
              // Add errors highlight
      username.removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');

      // Stop submission of the form
      e.preventDefault();

    }

        $.ajax({
            url: "form_login_process.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data:{'Username':username,'Password':password},
            success: function (data)
            {
             if(data === "true")
             {
            }
            else if(data === "false")
            {
            }
           },
    });
});
```

Modal

```
 <form role="form" method="post" id="login_Modal_checks">
  <div class="form-group has-error">
 <label for="username"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">                       </span>Username</label>  
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="loginUsername" id="loginUsername" placeholder="Enter username">
            </div>

<div class="form-group has-error">

<label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Password</label>

<input type="password" class="form-control" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Enter password">
 <i style="cursor: pointer" id="seePass" title="Click here to see password" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>

            </div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
 </div>

<a id="login_Modal"  class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</a>

         </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable username has just a value from input box.

For changing class you want to do something like below...

```
        if($("#loginUsername").val() === '') {
            $("#loginUsername").parent().addClass('has-error');
            $("#loginUsername").focus();
            errCount++;
        } else {
            $("#loginUsername").parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            if(errCount > 0) {
                errCount--;
            }
        }
```

and if you want to use username variable then, 
use

```
var username = $("#loginUsername");
```

Then you can treat username as element variable. and to check value you can use `username.val()`

and to change parent class

```
$("#loginUsername").parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
```

Also see that you need to use **.parent** as username's parent element has that class and you want to change that.

Comment: Superbb Job.
Jeo Shah g .. :)